# The double integral notation - which one is the initial double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Is $\displaystyle \int _ a^ b \left(\int_c^d f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, dx\right)\, dy$

a) $\displaystyle \int _ a^ b dy \int_ c^ d f(x,y)\,dx$

or

b) $\displaystyle \int _ a^ b dx \int_ c^ d f(x,y)\,dy$

?

Comment: How does $f_{X,Y}$ relate to $f$?

Comment: I see, the question is asking which integral you should evaluate first. What have you tried?

Comment: These are _iterated_ integrals. In some contexts it makes sense to distinguish between iterated integrals and double integrals. For example, $$ \int_0^1\left( \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \,dx\right) dy \ne \int_0^1\left( \int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \,dy \right) dx. $$ If the double integral exists, then these two iterated integrals would be equal to the double integral. The double integral does not exist in this case because the positive and negative parts both diverge to infinity, but the two iterated integrals have two different finite values. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int _ a^ b \left(\int _ c^ d f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, dx\right)\, dy$$ means integrate with respect to $x$ first and then integrate with respect to $y$ second, so 
$$ \int _ a^b dy{\int} _ c^ d f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx$$ would be the equivalent expression.

Comment: Your second expression could also (should) be read to mean $\left(\int _ a^b dy\right)\left({\int} _ c^ d f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\right).$ The operator notation has to be made explicit, IMO, and I don't think it is used here, as the second integral doesn't use it.

Comment: That's true, but of the given options this one makes the most sense.

Comment: It is bad practice to assume that some of the options *must* be true, and then go with the one being "the least false", however you try to justify which one that is.

Comment: I would generally agree with you, but in this case I have actually seen these notations used interchangeably in probability texts.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly (unless this was the intention of the problem), neither of a) or b) use proper notation:

For a) (throughout, I assume $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f(x,y)$) it says
$$\int _ a^b dy{\int} _ c^ d f(x,y)dx,$$ which should be read as
$$\left(\int _ a^b dy\right)\left({\int} _ c^ d f(x,y)\,dx\right)$$
as the convention here seems to be making the integral sign and the differential a parenthesis that encloses the integrand (note that an operator notation is also possible, but it is not used here). This evaluates to $$(b-a)\left({\int} _ c^ d f(x,y)\,dx\right),$$ which is clearly not the same a the original expression.

For b), it is the same story, but with $x$ instead, i.e., still not the same as the original.

Rather, the original integral would normally be written 
$$\displaystyle \int _ a^ b \int _ c^ d f(x,y)\, dx\, dy,$$
where it is implicit that you first carry out the integration for the "inner" variable (here $x$), evaluate at the limits and then take the resulting expression and integrate it w.r.t. the outer variable (here $y$).